# How to apply aspect to all the newly created files in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

i want to add a aspect in Alfresco to add my custom metadata, i just want to to know that how can i add this aspect to all the newly created files.

the custom metadata files are added in the \Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension
directory.

Answer (score 3):

Add for example a rule to the folder your uploading to that is configured with an "Add aspect" action when new files are created.

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to add rules to add a aspect to all the files created in the space but the properties are still not getting added.

Comment: The properties are added only if you give a value to those. Otherwise you'll not find those properties in the node.properties list.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add an aspect to *all* content added to Alfresco regardless of the location, you'd better use a `JavaBehavior` attached to the `OnCreateNodePolicy`.

You can check [some](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2c/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/forum/ForumPostBehaviours.java) [Alfresco](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/modules/recordsmanagement/HEAD/rm-server/source/java/org/alfresco/module/org_alfresco_module_rm/model/behaviour/RecordContainerType.java) classes for an example of how to create your custom behavior, it goes roughly as follows (uses `cm:content` to attach the behavior to every document):

```
public class AddAspectBehavior implements NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy
{
    /** Policy component */
    private PolicyComponent policyComponent;

    /** Node service */
    private NodeService nodeService;

    /** Dictionary service */
    private DictionaryService dictionaryService;

    // TODO: add setters for the services

    public void init()
    {
        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME, 
                ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, 
                new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateNode", NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT));
    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef)
    {
        Map<QName,Serializable> aspectValues = new HashMap<QName,Serializable>();
        // TODO: add relevand properties
        nodeService.addAspect(childAssocReg.getChildRef(), MyCustomModel.ASPECT_TO_ADD, props);
    }
}
```

Then, on some Spring context file:

```
<bean id="my_package_behaviors_AddAspect"
      class="my.package.AddAspectBehavior"
      init-method="init">
      <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService"/>
      <property name="policyComponent" ref="policyComponent"/>
</bean>
```